# Get dynamic height for UICollectionViewCell with custom layout

Tags: ios, collectionview

I need to create an UICollectionView with variable cell height but keeping a fixed vertical gap between cells. Something like [this](https://github.com/MagicLab-team/PinterestLayout)

I found a lot of examples, tutorials and libraries out there but all these need to implement a delegate method providing the height for each item.
My cells have a number of labels which can have one or more lines so I don't know in advance the final height of an element after the cell layouts its views.

Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate your cell height with `systemLayoutSizeFitting` function.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622623-systemlayoutsizefitting

For example: (`UICollectionViewCell` is a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` so you can use this for cell and header/footer too)

```
public extension UICollectionReusableView {
    static func autoResizingView<T: UICollectionReusableView>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        let nibViews = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(T.identifier, owner: nil, options: nil)
        return nibViews?.first as? T ?? T()
    }

    static func autoLayoutSize<T: UICollectionReusableView>(type: T.Type, targetWidth: CGFloat, configure: ((T) -> Void)?) -> CGSize {
        let resizingView = UICollectionReusableView.autoResizingView(type: type)
        resizingView.prepareForReuse()
        configure?(resizingView)
        resizingView.setNeedsLayout()
        resizingView.layoutIfNeeded()

        let targetSize = CGSize(width: targetWidth, height: 0)
        let calculateView: UIView
        if let contentView = (resizingView as? UICollectionViewCell)?.contentView {
            calculateView = contentView
        } else {
            calculateView = resizingView
        }
        // Calculate the size (height) using Auto Layout
        let autoLayoutSize = calculateView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
            targetSize,
            withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
            verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)
        return autoLayoutSize
    }
}
```